# How do I use AES-GMAC with a secret in BCrypt?

Tags: c++, windows, cryptography, aes-gcm, cng

I am trying to use AES-GMAC with BCrypt (Microsoft CNG if that helps) but the documentation seems contradictory to what I would expect.

[RFC 4543](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4543) states that AES-GMAC requires a secret key (which I was expecting), but [BCryptCreateHash function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptcreatehash) states that `pbSecret` is not used unless the `BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE_HMAC` is provided.

I've tried using the `BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE_HMAC` on `BcryptOpenAlgorithmProvider` and as I expected, I get a `NOT_SUPPORTED` when using `BCRYPT_AES_GMAC_ALGORITHM` with `BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE_HMAC`.

The process I was expecting was something like:

```cxx
BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(*with no HMAC flag*)
BCryptCreateHash(*including secret*)
BCryptHashData()
BCryptFinaliseHash()
```

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried using the `BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE_HMAC` on `BcryptOpenAlgorithmProvider` and as I expected, I get a `NOT_SUPPORTED` when using `BCRYPT_AES_GMAC_ALGORITHM` with `BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE_HMAC`.

`BCRYPT_AES_GMAC_ALGORITHM` seems broken. Don't use it.

Use AES/GCM via `BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM`. Don't encrypt any data. Only authenticate the aad. The resulting tag is the GMAC over the AAD.

---

> How do I use AES-GMAC with a secret in BCrypt?

The steps to create the GMAC are:

- Get AES algorithm
- Set GCM mode
- Key the cipher
- Set the nonce
- Authenticate the aad

*"aad"* is *"additionally authenticated data"*. It is different than plain text data that is traditionally encrypted.

Programs to MAC the aad are below for both Bcrypt and Crypto++. Since you don't encrypt data, the call to `BCryptEncrypt` looks like:

```
status = BCryptEncrypt(
    hKey,
    NULL, 0,
    (PVOID)&aadInfo,
    NULL, 0,
    NULL, 0,
    &ulWritten,
    0
);
```

***Note well***: [SP800-38D](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38d/final) specifies max nonce of 2<sup>64</sup>-1, but Microsoft limits the nonce to 12 bytes. If you try to use 16 bytes, which is AES blocksize, then the result is `0xc000000d` or `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. The Microsoft docs fail to document the limitations.

---

Here is the Microsoft Bcrypt program.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <bcrypt.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

#pragma comment (lib, "bcrypt.lib")

std::string NtStatusToString(const CHAR* operation, NTSTATUS status)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << operation << ", 0x" << std::hex << status;

    switch(status)
    {
        case 0xc0000000:
            oss << " (STATUS_SUCCESS)";
            break;
        case 0xC0000008:
            oss << " (STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE)";
            break;
        case 0xc000000d:
            oss << " (STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER)";
            break;
        case 0xc00000bb:
            oss << " (STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED)";
            break;
        case 0xC0000225:
            oss << " (STATUS_NOT_FOUND)";
            break;
    }
    return oss.str();
}

std::string ArrayToHexString(const UCHAR arr[], size_t size)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0');
        oss << (unsigned int)arr[i];
    }
    return oss.str();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE hAlgorithm = 0;
    BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE hKey = 0;
    UCHAR* pbKeyObject = 0;
    ULONG cbKeyObjectLength = 0;

    // SP800-38D specifies max nonce of 2^64-1, but
    // Microsoft limits the nonce to 12 bytes.

    UCHAR key[16] = {0};
    UCHAR  iv[12] = {0};
    UCHAR tag[16] = {0};

    // The data to be GMAC'd. It is not encrypted.
    std::string aad("Not so secret additionally authenticated data");

    try
    {
        NTSTATUS status = 0;
        ULONG ulWritten = 0;

        ////////////////////////////////////////

        status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(
            &hAlgorithm,
            BCRYPT_AES_ALGORITHM,
            NULL, 0
        );

        if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status))
            throw std::runtime_error(
                NtStatusToString("BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider", status));

        status = BCryptSetProperty(
            hAlgorithm,
            BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE,
            (UCHAR*)BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM,
            sizeof(BCRYPT_CHAIN_MODE_GCM),
            0
        );

        if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status))
            throw std::runtime_error(
                NtStatusToString("BCryptSetProperty (BCRYPT_CHAINING_MODE)", status));

        ////////////////////////////////////////

        status = BCryptGetProperty(
            hAlgorithm,
            BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH,
            (PUCHAR)&cbKeyObjectLength,
            sizeof(cbKeyObjectLength),
            &ulWritten,
            0
        );

        if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status))
            throw std::runtime_error(
                NtStatusToString("BCryptGetProperty (BCRYPT_OBJECT_LENGTH)", status));

        pbKeyObject = new UCHAR[cbKeyObjectLength];

        if (!pbKeyObject)
            throw std::runtime_error("pbKeyObject");

        ////////////////////////////////////////

        status = BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey(
            hAlgorithm,
            &hKey,
            pbKeyObject,
            cbKeyObjectLength,
            key,
            sizeof(key),
            0
        );

        if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status))
            throw std::runtime_error(
                NtStatusToString("BCryptGenerateSymmetricKey", status));

        ////////////////////////////////////////

        BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO aadInfo;
        BCRYPT_INIT_AUTH_MODE_INFO(aadInfo);

        aadInfo.pbNonce = iv;
        aadInfo.cbNonce = sizeof(iv);

        // Awful API design; non-const pointer.
        aadInfo.pbAuthData = reinterpret_cast<UCHAR*>(&aad[0]);
        aadInfo.cbAuthData = static_cast<ULONG>(aad.size());
        aadInfo.cbAAD = static_cast<ULONG>(aad.size());

        aadInfo.pbTag = tag;
        aadInfo.cbTag = sizeof(tag);

        ////////////////////////////////////////

        status = BCryptEncrypt(
            hKey,
            NULL, 0,
            (PVOID)&aadInfo,
            NULL, 0,
            NULL, 0,
            &ulWritten,
            0
        );

        if (!BCRYPT_SUCCESS(status))
            throw std::runtime_error(
                NtStatusToString("BCryptEncrypt", status));

        std::cout << "Message: " << aad << std::endl;
        std::cout << "GMAC: " << ArrayToHexString(tag, sizeof(tag));
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    if (hKey)
        BCryptDestroyKey(hKey);

    if (hAlgorithm)
        BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(hAlgorithm, 0);

    // Destroy after handles
    if (pbKeyObject)
        delete [] pbKeyObject;

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the result.

```
>cl.exe /DWINVER=0x0600 /TP /GR /EHsc bcrypt-gmac.cpp /link
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24210 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

bcrypt-gmac.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:bcrypt-gmac.exe
bcrypt-gmac.obj

>.\bcrypt-gmac.exe
Message: Not so secret additionally authenticated data
GMAC: 3a1158d288cd796899f0366cdf594020
```

---

Here is the code for [Crypto++](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GCM_Mode). You can do the same in [Botan](https://botan.randombit.net/handbook/api_ref/cipher_modes.html#aead-mode) or [OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption).

```
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "hex.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "gcm.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    byte key[16] = {0};
    byte  iv[12] = {0};
    byte tag[16] = {0};

    std::string aad("Not so secret additionally authenticated data");

    try
    {
        GCM< AES >::Encryption enc;
        enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

        // AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter defines two
        //   channels: DEFAULT_CHANNEL and AAD_CHANNEL
        //   DEFAULT_CHANNEL is encrypted and authenticated,
        //   AAD_CHANNEL is authenticated.
        AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter ef(enc,
            new ArraySink(tag, sizeof(tag)),
            false, 16 /* Tag size, MAC_AT_END */
        ); // AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter

        // Authenticated data *must* be pushed before
        //  Confidential/Authenticated data. Otherwise
        //  we must catch the BadState exception
        ef.ChannelPut(AAD_CHANNEL, (const byte*)aad.data(), aad.size());
        ef.ChannelMessageEnd(AAD_CHANNEL);

        // Confidential data comes after authenticated data.
        // This is a limitation due to CCM mode, not GCM mode.
        //ef.ChannelPut(DEFAULT_CHANNEL, pdata.data(), pdata.size());
        //ef.ChannelMessageEnd(DEFAULT_CHANNEL);

        // Signal end of message
        ef.MessageEnd();

        std::cout << "Message: " << aad << std::endl;
        std::cout << "GMAC: ";
        StringSource(tag, sizeof(tag), true, new HexEncoder(new FileSink(std::cout)));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    catch(CryptoPP::Exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the result.

```
$ g++ test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe

$ ./test.exe
Message: Not so secret additionally authenticated data
GMAC: 3A1158D288CD796899F0366CDF594020
```

Comment: Note that the Windows API limitation is suggested by NIST[1]: 
`For IVs, it is recommended that implementations restrict support to the length of 96 bits, to promote interoperability, efficiency, and simplicity of design.`
[1]https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf