# How to determine which of 23 parameters are STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER?

Tags: c, windows, cng

I'm trying to use `BCryptEncrypt` to authenticate some AAD but the function is failing with `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. `BCryptEncrypt` takes 10 parameters. One of the parameters is `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO`. `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` takes another 13 parameters.

Running my test program results in:

```
>.\bcrypt-gmac.exe
BCryptEncrypt error, 0xc000000d (STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER)
```

`STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` is not very helpful in this case.

My question is, how do I determine which of the 23 parameters is causing the error when using Bcrypt?

Is there a way to get extended error information, like through `BcryptPropertyGet` (maybe a `LAST_ERROR_PARAMETER` or something similar)?

Or does Microsoft expect us to guess at the problem? In this case, I guess the answer is, *"you can't"*.

---

The Microsoft docs don't provide examples of using Bcrypt. I also cannot find helpful examples on Stack Overflow or MSDN. Even [Writing Secure Code for Windows Vista](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623937) fails to provide examples.

Here is the treatment in [Writing Secure Code for Windows Vista](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623937). It amounts to pseudo-code, which is very disappointing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Close voter: I'm not interested in having someone inspect my code. I want to learn which parameter is causing `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. 23 potential parameters (with combinations) is too many to eliminate through guessing.

Comment: Example code for `BCryptEncrypt` does exist ([here for example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/encrypting-data-with-cng)) though doesn't seem to handle authenticated cipher mode. The fields for [`BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_authenticated_cipher_mode_info) do seem decently documented though. I could also find an example of authenticated encryption on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30958068/20270).

Comment: @Hasturkun - Nice find on the CNG examples. Microsoft docs don't provide sample code or link to them. Confer, [BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptopenalgorithmprovider) (and friends). Be careful of the Microsoft docs for [BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/ns-bcrypt-bcrypt_authenticated_cipher_mode_info). There are at least 2 errors and omissions. Getting back to the question, do you know how to get more information when a call fails with `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`?

Comment: Debug it? It might validate all the parameters at the start of the function if you are lucky.

Answer (score 0):

I spent the better part of the day today struggling with this very issue. While I don't have a good way to answer your question as to how to determine, in a generic way, which parameter exactly is bad, I'll leave these few tidbits here for posterity:

1. The `cbTag` field of the `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` needs to be set from the beginning. The `pbTag` isn't necessary until the final call that produces or verifies the tag, but `cbTag` must always be present.
2. The `pbNonce` field of the `BCRYPT_AUTHENTICATED_CIPHER_MODE_INFO` structure must remain set for all calls when chaining calls together (by using `BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_CHAIN_CALLS_FLAG`).
3. All calls during a chain (again using `BCRYPT_AUTH_MODE_CHAIN_CALLS_FLAG`) of encryptions or decryptions, except for the last, must provide an input whose size is a multiple of the algorithm's block size. I think the documentation actually says this, but it's not abundantly clear when they explicitly tell you not to set the `BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING` flag (with authenticated ciphers).

The code I'm working on will eventually be part of the library [here](https://gitlab.com/ubiqsecurity/ubiq-c-cpp), which will hopefully provide a working example to the next person.